# How should I paint an exterior door to prevent sticking?

Tags: doors, paint

Most quality paints for doors have *at least* a 5-day full cure time.

So how can I paint an exterior door and keep it from sticking to the stop?

I mean I could obviously paint it first thing in the morning on a warm summer day and leave it open until I want to go to bed but that's not fully cured.

I'm considering removing the door, painting it, boarding up the opening, and going on vacation for a few days.... But there has to be a better way!

Answer (score 2):

- Wax paper. Secure it using tape to the edge of the door or the jamb.
- A thin coat of petroleum jelly. A professional painter told me this trick. The paint should be fairly dry first, not at all tacky.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't paint the portion that will touch the stop
- Swap in a spare door for a few days (habitat for humanity re-store has them quite reasonably priced, for instance.)
- Do the paint job on a new, or new-to-you used door, and only swap it once.