# How to prevent a painted surface from sticking to another?

Tags: paint

Due to deadlines, for example, it can be necessary to attach a painted surface to another surface (possibly painted as well) that is dry enough to handle, but still not fully dried/cured/.... such that the mating surfaces will stick when disassembled, causing tear off of the paint layer(s).  How can this be prevented ?

For example, last minute making a custom picture frame with photo for a present, say your daughter's Dobbs based wedding, or be more creative than I.

Comment: Consider an oil finish? Shellac might also wr, since its solvent is alcohol. Or a wax.

Comment: Duplicate? See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/193474/97780

Comment: Elevate the temperature for a few hours if possible that will help a lot with most paints but that is a guess based on the type of paint you did not tell us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I paint an exterior door to prevent sticking?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/193474/how-should-i-paint-an-exterior-door-to-prevent-sticking) Personally, I'd go with the Vaseline suggestion on the dupe.